# VF page not closing upon 'save'

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, redirect, salesforce1-platform

I'm having an issue with this visualforce page.  I'm able to save the record with my logic, but it won't listen to redirect to the 'saveRecord' method in the class.  When I select a record, it does save it but doesn't close and redirect the page to the previous page.  Any help would be wonderful.  Thanks ahead of time!

**Before I click 'Save'**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwmUb.jpg]

**Then the record saves, but doesn't close the VF page container and redirect.**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z7Bj.jpg]

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Lab__c" extensions="MassAssociateController" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">  

<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/35.0/apex.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS092, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />           
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS092, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}" />

<apex:form >

<div class="slds">
        <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
          <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
              <div class="slds-media">
                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--large slds-icon-standard-user">
                      <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds092, 'assets/icons/custom-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#custom58')}" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
        <div class="slds-media__body">
            <p class="slds-text-heading--label">{!Lab__c.Name}</p>
                <div class="slds-grid">
                    <h1 class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal" title="Record Title">Equipment Association</h1>
                <div class="slds-col slds-shrink-none">             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br />   

 <nav role="navigation">
  <p id="bread-crumb-label" class="slds-assistive-text"></p>
  <ol class="slds-breadcrumb slds-list--horizontal" aria-labelledby="bread-crumb-label">
    <li class="slds-list__item slds-text-heading--label">{!Lab__c.Account_Name_VF__c}</li>
  </ol>
</nav> 
</div>
</div>


<apex:PageBlock >   
  <div align="center" draggable="false">        
              <apex:commandbutton style="float:centre" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand" value="Save" action="{!saveRecord}"/>             
               <!-- &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <apex:commandbutton style="float:centre" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/> -->                                         
  </div>

  <script>
  if((typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
  sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recId,'detail');
  }
  </script>

</apex:PageBlock>



  <apex:pageBlock >      

      <apex:pageBlockTable styleClass="slds-table slds-table--bordered" value="{!cb}" var="Equipment">



          <apex:column >

          <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!Equipment.s}"/>





          </apex:column>

          <apex:column value="{!Equipment.t.Name}"/>

          <apex:column value="{!Equipment.t.Account_Name__c}"/>

          <apex:column value="{!Equipment.t.Product_Category__c}"/>

          <apex:column value="{!Equipment.t.System_Manufacturer__c}"/>

          <apex:column value="{!Equipment.t.Version_Type__c}"/>

          <apex:column value="{!Equipment.t.Warranty_Status__c }"/>

      </apex:pageBlockTable>



  </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public class MassAssociateController {
    string recId;
    /*public String getsaveRecord() {
        system.debug('this is test method');
        return null;
    }*/

    public list<Equipment__c> equip{get;set;}
    public List<checkbox> cb{get;set;}

    public MassAssociateController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        recId = controller.getRecord().Id;

        cb=getData();

    }

    public List<checkbox> getData(){
        Lab__c recName=[SELECT Account_Name__c FROm Lab__c WHERE Id =:recId];  

        equip = [SELECT Name, Account_Name__c,Account_Name__r.Name, Product_Category__c, System_Manufacturer__c, Version_Type__c, Warranty_Status__c FROM Equipment__c WHERE Account_Name__c=:recName.Account_Name__c AND Account_Name__c != NULL AND Lab__c =null  ];

        cb = new List<checkbox>();

        for(Equipment__c pe: equip) {
            cb.add(new checkbox(false,pe));
        }

        return cb;
    }

    public class checkbox{

        public Boolean s{get;set;}
        public Equipment__c t {get;set;}

        public checkbox(Boolean s,Equipment__c t){        
            this.s=s;
            this.t=t;
        }
    }

     public pageReference saveRecord(){  

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+recId);
        pageRef.setredirect(true);


        List<Equipment__c> lstEqu = new  List<Equipment__c>();
        system.debug('cb======='+cb);
        system.debug('recId===='+recId);

        for(checkbox wapper:cb ){
            system.debug('wapper.s======='+wapper.s);
            // check this record is selected or not
            if(wapper.s == true){
                lstEqu.add(wapper.t);// selected records are add to list        
            }
        }

        for(Equipment__c obj:lstEqu){

            obj.Lab__c= recId;

        }

        update lstEqu;
        return pageRef;
     }

    public pageReference cancelRecord(){

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+recId);
        pageRef.setredirect(true);

        return pageRef;

    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an onComplete action to your apex:commandbutton you can then either use JS or jQuery to refresh the page if it's not working correctly with setredirect()

Check this out: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm

Comment: I tried that with a script tag, and instead it redirected the page back (to the correct page), but the Classic version instead of the SF1 version of it.  
Code:
<script>
  'function myFunction(){
   sforce.one.back(true);   
  }
  </script>

Comment: Result: http://imgur.com/gallery/oxzuekP

Comment: @JoshuaDavis hmmmmm have a look here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213748&language=en_US they mention using a different format for SF1 links "salesforce1://sObject/001D000000Jwj9v/view"